# Why is xpath in Python not returning what it should be?

Tags: python, xpath

I am relatively new to HTML scraping and I have a small problem.
My code is as follows:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("http://champion.gg/statistics/#?sortBy=general.winPercent&order=descend")
champs = html.fromstring(page.content)

c = champs.xpath('//span[@class="stat-champ-title"]/text()')

print("champs:",c)
```

The HTML I am parsing is this

```
<span class="stat-champ-title ng-binding">Ivern</span>
```

When run, the code prints:

```
champs: ['{{champion.title}}']
```

I want champs to be a list of all the champions listed on that site, the first being Ivern. What am I doing wrong and what is indicated by the {{ and }}?

Comment: Because it is an *angular* file that is rendered by javascript. You need to run javascript first and obtain the working DOM for that. What you obtain is the **correct** source code. It is only angular that later fills in the content.

Comment: The site (as well as Riot) has an API, have you tried getting the data that way?